In my tokens asset I have one token which values is shown in us$ but how I can sell that token
In bscscan it is showing total tokens and value of that tokens, one token is such that the value showing in 100$ but how can I sell that token. I am not getting any rate of that tokens in metamask. Can anyone help

Could you share the token address?

You can use a DEX, like SushiSwap, or a CEX, like Binance, to sell these tokens, as long as the protocol you choose supports it and has liquidity.
If the token was sent to you randomly without you buying it, be careful as sometimes scammers create malicious token contracts, hoping you'll interact with the unverified code so they can steal your tokens.
